# How to optimize performance of stored procedures

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have two tables in my database which store around 1.3million records each. It takes a lot of time to execute queries in these tables. I have a SQL Server job that queries through stored procedures into these tables. These are simple select,updated and create queries.
Some findings:
Logical operator AND is used excessively.
Temporary tables are created and dropped.
Inner joins have been used.
Non clustered index has been used in table 1. 
Custered index Primary key exists in both the tables. 
Sql Tuning gives no suggestions.
Estimat Execution Plan gives query cost of 50%
There are several parameters used in these stored procedures.

The job takes around 20-25 minutes to execute. I need to bring it down to 5mins max. Please guide.

Comment: The way you've positioned this problem sounds more like a "help wanted" advert. which isn't allowed here :-) You could perhaps use the actual execution plans to identify problematic sub-sections of individual queries and post them here. But it's also possible that you need overall server tune-up, which, again, will have to be identified on your end and dissected to SO-style questions. Again - they way you've asked it looks like 5K consulting opening :-)

Comment: Post your table structure here so we could understand how to optimise it

Comment: As per usual: take apart your queries - which part of them costs the most time? Can adding an index help speed it up? Can you possible eliminate creating and dropping the temp table? Can you limit the amount of data queried by using more stringent `WHERE` clauses? It's really not rocket science - just performance tuning ....